# PHP - bootstrap controller for views

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm having problem with this lines of code; 
When i go to  **localhost/**  site work!
When i go to  **localhost/welcome**  site not work! go to echo ==> ***string*** , ***FAIL***
When i go to  **localhost/welcome/other**  site **work** but with error down bellow!
Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method welcome::king() should not be called statically in bootstrap.php on line => call_user_func_array([$this->_controller, $this->_methode], $this->_params);

Code in bootstrap.php

```
if(empty($url)) 
                {
                    $name_controller = ROOT;
                    $this->_requireController($name_controller);
                    $contro = new $name_controller();
                    $contro->$name_controller();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $this->_controller = $url[0];

                    if(isset($url[1]))
                    {
                        $this->_methode = $url[1];
                        unset($url[0]);
                        unset($url[1]);

                        $this->_params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
                        echo "222";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        echo "string";
                    }

                    $this->_requireController($this->_controller);
                    $contro = new $this->_controller();

                    if(method_exists($contro, $this->_methode))
                    {
                        call_user_func_array([$this->_controller, $this->_methode], $this->_params);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        echo 'FAIL';
                    }

                }
            }
```

**Controllers/welcome.php**

class welcome extends Controller
{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function welcome() 
{
  echo "work!";
}
public function other()
{
  echo "Other Work";
}
public function other_arg($arg)
{
  echo "Other Work with ".$arg;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the line with the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error on **loclahost/welcome/other**:
**222**
Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method welcome::test() should not be called statically in C:\xampp-server\htdocs\bootstrap.php on line 177
**Other Work**

Comment: non-static method   i know for this if i do in welcome.php controller   like  public static function  will work  but then can not use  inside this  $this->route->run();  or $this->action->execute();

Answer (score 0):

You can make it static and call it form a non static function like this:

```
static::run();
```

or have you tried this

```
$this->-controller->$this->_methode($args);
```

instead of

```
call_user_func_array([$this->_controller, $this->_methode], $this->_params);
```

Comment: The problem is that with static  i cannot use like this... 
`$this->route->run();
$this->action->execute()
$this->config->set()`

Comment: If i made static the problem is that i cant get  just first $arg   other now show  like  localhost/welcome/other/kingsiller/300/1 
It wil lshow just welcome/other + kingsiller  :/